# python call an executable file wait for the file to be generated add or rename _completed.xml

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I want to call an executable from python wait for the process to generate the file
return name of the file + _completed eg example.xml is the file which the executable generates then return name of the generated file with _complete
so it should return example_complete.xml back here is my code

```
import subprocess
import requests
import xmltodict

xml_input=r'c:\workingfolder\customers.xml'
form_inputs='a:b:c'

def run_excel_again(xml_input,form_inputs):
  subprocess.Popen(['c:\\path to my excel.exe',xml_input,'/c',form_inputs])
 #check if file is created takes about a minute to generate file
 #subprocess.wait()-- is this possible how to check if the file generation 
  #   is completed --pass filename_completed.xml to 
  #another function  run_excel_again2(filename_completed.xml) 
   print('processing completed')
 return(filename.xml,filename_completed.xml)

run_excel_again(xml_input,form_inputs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def run_excel_again(xml_input,form_inputs):
p= subprocess.Popen(['c:\\path to my excel.exe',xml_input,'/c',form_inputs])
#check if file is created takes about a minute to generate file
p.wait(timeout=none)-- Adding this statement worked for me 
#   is completed --pass filename_completed.xml to 
#another function  run_excel_again2(filename_completed.xml) 
print('processing completed')
return(filename.xml,filename_completed.xml)
```

It just needed this line of code

```
p.wait(timeout=none)
```